# Boost Graph accessing properties through vertex_descriptor

Tags: c++, boost, graph, boost-graph

I have my custom vertex and edge properties

```
namespace boost { 
    enum vertex_diagonal_t{vertex_diagonal = 999};
    BOOST_INSTALL_PROPERTY(vertex, diagonal);
}
namespace boost { 
    enum edge_dominance_t{edge_dominance = 998};
    BOOST_INSTALL_PROPERTY(edge, dominance);
}
```

I create my adjacency list with `boost::property`

```
typedef boost::adjacency_list<
      boost::listS, 
      boost::vecS,
      boost::bidirectionalS,
      boost::property<boost::vertex_diagonal_t, const khut::diagonal*>,
      boost::property<boost::edge_dominance_t,  float>
    > diagonal_dominance_graph;
typedef boost::property_map<diagonal_dominance_graph, boost::vertex_diagonal_t>::type diagonal_map_type;
typedef boost::property_map<diagonal_dominance_graph, boost::edge_dominance_t>::type  dominance_map_type;
```

Now I want to loop through my own containers and add vertex

```
diagonal_dominance_graph graph;
  for(storage_type::const_iterator i = repo_begining.begin(); i != repo_begining.end(); ++i){
    diagonal_dominance_graph::vertex_descriptor dia_vertex = boost::add_vertex(graph);

    //>> ?? HOW CAN I write Properties to dia_vertex HERE ?

    //boost::property<boost::vertex_diagonal_t, const khut::diagonal*> p;
    //boost::put(p, dia_vertex);

  }
```

What I am not getting is How can I set properties of a vertex through `vertex_descriptor`. may be I am missing a simple function.

Please I don't need anything that makes BGL even more complex, or something that cleans and restructures the types in my example. I just need to know how to read/write properties through a `vertex_descriptor` or `edge_descriptor`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using property lists: they're [documented here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/graph/doc/using_adjacency_list.html#sec:custom-vertex-properties).

So in your example, you'd use

```
diagonal_map_type  vp = get(boost::vertex_diagonal, graph);

using storage_type = std::vector<int>;
storage_type repo_begining(10);

for(storage_type::const_iterator i = repo_begining.begin(); i != repo_begining.end(); ++i) {
    diagonal_dominance_graph::vertex_descriptor dia_vertex = boost::add_vertex(graph);


    khut::diagonal* v = nullptr;
    boost::put(vp, dia_vertex, v);
}

// likewise for edges
dominance_map_type ep = get(boost::edge_dominance, graph);
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ac8f2f311345133b)**

### Bundled Properties

The very same documentation page says:

> **NOTE**: The Boost Graph Library supports two interchangeable methods for specifying interior properties: bundled properties and property lists. The former is easier to use and requires less effort, whereas the latter is compatible with older, broken compilers and is backward-compatible with Boost versions prior to 1.32.0. If you absolutely require these compatibility features, read on to learn about property lists. ***Otherwise, we strongly suggest that you read about the bundled properties mechanism.***

Boost 1.32 dates over 10 years ago! So, I'd suggest bundled properties:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aa039e6a040788bd)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>

namespace khut {
    struct diagonal { };

    struct MyVertexProperties {
        diagonal const* diag_ptr;
    };

    struct MyEdgeProperties {
        float dominance;
    };
}

typedef boost::adjacency_list<
      boost::listS, 
      boost::vecS,
      boost::bidirectionalS,
      khut::MyVertexProperties,
      khut::MyEdgeProperties
    > diagonal_dominance_graph;

#include <iostream>


int main() {
    using namespace boost;

    diagonal_dominance_graph g;

    khut::diagonal d1, d2;
    {
        auto v1 = add_vertex(khut::MyVertexProperties { &d1 }, g);
        auto v2 = add_vertex(khut::MyVertexProperties { &d2 }, g);

        /*auto e1 = */add_edge(v1, v2, khut::MyEdgeProperties { 42.31415926 }, g);
    }

    for(diagonal_dominance_graph::vertex_descriptor vd : make_iterator_range(vertices(g)))
        std::cout << "Is diagonal d1? " << std::boolalpha << (&d1 == g[vd].diag_ptr) << "\n";
    for(diagonal_dominance_graph::edge_descriptor ed : make_iterator_range(edges(g)))
        std::cout << "Edge dominance: " << g[ed].dominance << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
Is diagonal d1? true
Is diagonal d1? false
Edge dominance: 42.3142
```

Comment: I am not using C++11. and yes I can use my own structs as bundled properties. But how to handle old `boost::property` thing ?

Comment: (Also, c++ has been c++11 for some years now. The fact that I used c++11 in my sample shouldn't detract anything from the usefulness for you. Just modify what needs modification)

Comment: Yes I agree that using boost::property is more complex than doing it with your own structures. But I'd like to know how to do it with boost::property. and I've seen some previous answers in So that instead of focusing on actual questions tend to restructure the classes, and typedefs in question's example. that I wanted to avoid :)

Comment: @NeelBasu I've updated the answer with the sample I had given in the comment. It answers the question now :)

Comment: Thanks. So you need to do `boost::get` before adding any vertex to the graph.

Comment: Nope. You can use `boost::get` to get the property map you want to use. You can call it whenever needed

Comment: Yes so you can get a property map that may **not** have the target vertex of which you are trying to set properties at that moment. However once you add some vertex that gets automatically populated in *that* map. so you can access that using `boost::get`

Comment: One more question. what will be the return type of `boost::get(&MyVertexProperties::diag_ptr, graph)` ? in case of Bundled properties ?

Comment: @NeelBasu it's in the docs under ["Properties maps from bundled properties"](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/graph/doc/bundles.html)

Comment: No the type is not clearly written on that page. I've another property of enum type colour. and I figured out the following `typedef boost::property_map<
       khut::util::diagonal::reduction::diagonal_dominance_graph, 
       khut::util::diagonal::reduction::colors khut::util::diagonal::reduction::edge_properties::*>::type  edge_colours_map_type;` as working at last

Comment: @NeelBasu Which is exactly what that page, clearly, states: _"With bundled properties, we can just pass a member pointer as the property for get"_ and even, explicitly (redundantly) _"The type of the returned property map is property_map<Map, double Highway::*>::type or property_map<Map, double Highway::*>::const_type, depending on whether the graph map is non-constant or constant."_. That's basically all the content of that heading, modulo the example.